# Create a list of subrooms in quickblox

Tags: quickblox

How can I create a room and let that room lead to list of sub-rooms . Users will be able to select this room and select which of the sub-rooms they will love to join. How can I do this in quickblox

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality for this, but you can use Custom objects module to achieve such structure, for example create 2 entities: Rooms and SubRooms. SubRoom will have a field with link to ID of Room.

iOS CustomObjects code sample http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios

Android code sample http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-android